# $.extend - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been trying to search and found some answers about jQuery conflicts, DOM ready, etc.. but didn't solved it. I've been getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "offer.testB.Amount"  of
>   undefined

actually all calls from testB inside my "$.extend" have this error. I'm new to this, so if anybody could help, would appreciate it. Thanks

```
offer: Object
 testA:""
 testB: Object
    Amount:143.78
    Currency:"USD"
    ExchangeRate:1.123
  testC :""



$.extend(offer, {
      sampleA: offer.testA,
      sampleB: offer.testB.Amount,
      sampleC: true
  }
```

Update: Just found out even outside of the `$.extend` just a simple `var test = offer.testB.Amount` shows the error above

Comment: May be you need `offer = $.extend({}, offer, {
      sampleA: offer.testA,
      sampleB: offer.testB.Amount,
      sampleC: true
  }}`

Comment: @Satpal  seems right here.  DJ_lethal  Try once his code

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks though I just found out even outside of the `$.extend` just a simple `var test = offer.testB.Amount` shows the error above